# Access variable from another form in c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

So I have a method that calculates the value of some variables in Form1 using variables from Form2 (I accessed them using getters and setters). Now when I invoke this method in my Form2 it doesn't apply the chages to the calculated variables.
I also tried to just move the Calculate method in my Form2 and get the needed variables from Form1 to Form2 but I can't get them all. So I would prefer that method stay in Form1.
What can I do?
(hope it made some kind of sense)

Comment: please provide the implementation of the 2 form classes with the method and variables in question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use an event in form2 which passes information to form1.

Create a property for each value which goes to form1 e.g.

```
public class Calculation
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Form2, two TextBox,one Button

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public delegate void OnPushValues(Calculation sender);
        public event OnPushValues Push;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PushButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out var value1) && 
                int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out var value2))
            {
                Push?.Invoke(new Calculation() { Value1 = value1, Value2 = value2 });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form1

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowChildFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form = new Form2();
            form.Push += OnPush;
            form.ShowDialog();
            form.Push -= OnPush;
        }

        private void OnPush(Calculation sender)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(sender.Value1 + sender.Value2);
        }
    }
}
```